# RuntimeError: The full_object_detection must use the iBUG 300W 68 point face landmark style

Tags: python, dlib

I would like to compile this program : https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/face_clustering.py

But I received this error message:

Processing file: ../examples/faces/2008_002079.jpg

Number of faces detected: 6

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_clustering_new.py", line 87, in 
    face_descriptor = facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
RuntimeError: The full_object_detection must use the iBUG 300W 68 point face landmark style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I called program like

python3 face_clustering_new.py ../dlib-models/shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat ../dlib-models/dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat ../examples/faces output_folder

I used python3.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

> shape_predictor_**5**_face_landmarks.dat

with

> shape_predictor_**68**_face_landmarks.dat

It is availbale [here](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2)